# Why, if $\mathcal{H}$ is separable, there exists a sequence $\{f_k\}$ in $\mathcal{H}$ s.t. $\overline{\operatorname{span}}\{f_k\}=\mathcal{H}$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. Why, if $\mathcal{H}$ is assumed separable, there exists a sequence $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{H}$ such that $\overline{\operatorname{span}}\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}=\mathcal{H}$? I know that a normed vector space, in which countable and dense family exists, is said to be separable. Definition of dense: A subset $Z \subseteq X$ (countable or not) is said to be dense in $X$ if for each $f \in X$ and each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $g \in Z$ such that
$$
\|f-g\| \leq \epsilon
$$

But how can I infer that $\overline{\operatorname{span}}\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}=\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You state the definition of separable from which your assertion immediately follows. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: This is the point: why my assertion immediately follows? I can't understand it.

Comment: What is your definition of _dense_?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: I see, now the question makes sense. I posted an answer (which also explains my initial confusion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another common definition of dense is the following: $Z \subseteq X$ is called dense if $\overline{Z} = X$.

To prove that they are equivalent, assume that $\overline{Z} \neq X$. This means that there is an open ball $B(x_0,\varepsilon) \subseteq X \setminus Z$. But then we cannot find a $z \in Z$ such that $\|x_0-z\| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

On the other hand, if $\overline{Z} = X$, then every $x \in X$ has a sequence $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $Z$ such that $z_n \to x$. But this means, we can always find a $z_n$ such that $\|x-z_n\| \leq \varepsilon$.

Hence the two definitions are equivalent.